# Different result between math kernel library and LAPACK

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, intel-mkl

I write the code that diagonalize a matrix as following

```
[[0,-2,-2,0]

[-2,0,0,-2]

[-2,0,0,-2]

[0,-2,-2,0]]
```

My C code with inter math kernel library (MKL) throws following result:

```
Eigenvalue : -4 0   0   4   

Eigenvector Matrix :
0.5 0.5 -0.5 0.5    
0.5 -0.5    -0.5    -0.5    
0.5 0.5 0.5 -0.5    
0.5 -0.5    0.5 0.5
```

Same code written in python using numpy shows following result:

```
Eigenvalue : -4 0   0 4 

Eigenvector Matrix :
0.5 0.707107    0           -0.5    
0.5 0           0.707107    0.5 
0.5 0           -0.707107   0.5 
0.5 -0.707107   0           -0.5
```

In short, **I observe same eigenvalue set but different eigenvectors between mkl and numpy**. Mathematica guruantees the result of python, but mkl result also satisfies the orthogonality and reconstructs original matrix by similarity transformation of diagonal matrix of eigenvalue.

A diagonalization routine in mkl I used is as following

```
LAPACKE_dsyev(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR,'V','U',dim,&evec[0],dim,&eval[0]);
```

while in python, I used

```
eigval,eigvec = np.linalg.eigh(H)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Theoretically, the eigenvalue 0 has multiplicity 2, and the eigenspace associated with it is two dimensional.  In effect, the codes have found different bases for that eigenspace, but that's OK, because the basis is not unique.  (The eigenspace itself is unique.)

Comment: Ah. Thanks, I understand. Then, is there any reason that the mkl routine shows differnt eigenvector set from other methods? I have tried Mathematical, OpenBLAS, BLAS, numpy routines that they gives same results. Do they apply different algorithm in there routine?

Comment: Yes they do :)! Numpy most likely uses BLAS or OpenBLAS under the hood, so no surprise there. If you build Numpy with MKL (or use Enthought's Python distribution, which is built with MKL), you'd find Numpy agreeing with MKL. The eigenvectors might also differ by a sign; the important thing is to make sure the definition of eigendecomposition holds, i.e., `H - np.dot(np.dot(eigvec, np.diag(eigval)), eigvec.T)` is close to machine precision.